# An array within an array of object

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I have this object returned:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
( 
    [@attributes] => Array 
    ( 
        [Desc] => Amount should be numeric. 
    ) 
) 
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
( 
    [@attributes] => Array 
    ( 
        [Desc] => Please enter your Reference Number. 
    ) 
) 
)
```

How can I get the desc values? I need to get both Desc Values('Amount should be numeric.' and 'Please enter your Reference Number. ')

I have tried:

```
$res = $str[0];
```

it returned:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object 
( 
    [@attributes] => Array 
    ( 
        [Desc] => Amount should be numeric. 
    ) 
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) and then access them as properties.

```
$node->attributes()->Desc
```

Comment: This answer is the same with scalpweb. Thanks too.

Comment: @Ponce Certainly is. But looking at the post date/time, it might be worth flipping the subjects :)

Comment: @Scalpweb answered it 2minutes earlier. And I can only choose one. so far both works well.

Comment: @Ponce You must have funny views on how time works :) Anyway, I'm not worried.

Comment: oh sry.. my mind is conjested cant think properly, nearly done though. edited accepted answer. Thank you again

Comment: @Ponce You didn't need to change the accepted answer. Award it to whoever's answer was most clearest and helpful to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your object is a SimpleXML object.

You can learn how to use it here:

http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php

To solve your issue, you can use this:

```
$res0 = $str[0]->attributes()->Desc;
$res1 = $str[1]->attributes()->Desc;
```